# Producer/Consumer на Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, csv, xlsx

Всем, доброго времени суток.

Такой вот вопрос. Нужно реализовать парсер файлов, который будет выводить информацию в виде JSON.
Программе через командную строку вводим путь до файла json/csv/xlsx формата и она нам в командную строку выводит сформированные json строки.

Без Spring, программа работает на "ура". Но вот введение Spring,  которым я никогда не работал, в мою многопоточную программу вызывает кучу вопросов и сразу ломаются и потоки и логика программы. По сему, прошу помощи.

В кратце опишу классы.
Есть класс Producer, который читает файл и закидывает строку в виде LinkedList в BlockingQueue

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

int i = 0;
private Handler handler;


Producer() {
}

public Producer(Handler handler) {

    this.handler = handler;
}
// какая-то логика чтения файла
}
```

Класс Consumer, вычитывает очередь из BlockingQueue.

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

 private Handler handler;

Consumer() {
}

public Consumer(Handler handler) {

    this.handler = handler;
}
//некая логика класса Consumer
 }
```

Класс Handler является связующим классом, между Producer/Consumer. Он определяет расширение файла, местоположение файла, в нем хранятся флаги и т.д.

```
public class Handler {





    private Writer writer;


    @Resource(name = "jsonReader")
    private Reader jsonReader;

    @Resource(name = "csvReader")
    private Reader csvReader;

    @Resource(name = "xlsxReader")
    private Reader xlsxReader;


    private boolean isFileEnd = false;
    private String filename = "";
    private Path filePath;
    private String fileExtension = "none";
    private File file;
    private BlockingQueue<LinkedList> queue;

    public Handler() {
    }


    Handler(Writer writer,Reader reader,  int count) {

        this.reader = reader;
        this.writer = writer;
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(count);

    }
//некая логика класса 
}
```

Есть еще отдельные классы для каждого расширения.

Основной вопрос состоит в том, как сделать Handler бином и в зависимости от расширения файла создавать Reader внутри Handler либо jsonReader, либо другой какой-либо.

Если читать файл в формате  json и насильно указать в Handler, чтобы он использовал Reader в качестве jsonReader, то все работает.

Почитал про возможность использования MAP для конструктора класса, но как его применить, так и не понял. 
Сейчас все инструкции записаны в xml, но рад буду и формату в аннотациях, мне не принципиально.

Comment: Ну так все параметры вынести из конструктора и создавать экземпляр как бин и конфигурировать его при создании. @Bean public Handler getHandler() { Handler h = new Handler(); h.set(.......... return h; }

Comment: Спринг вроде как не для многопоточных систем .

Comment: @GenCloud - Спасибо, но как в итоге сделать, чтобы выбор Reader формировался в зависимости от расширения файла?

Comment: @Санаев тогда как обработать файл, в котором больше миллиона строк? В 1 потоке это будет очень долго.

Comment: @Санаев, не вводите людей в заблуждение ...

Comment: @zolt я имею в виду веб сервис

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете объявить бин в классе, помеченным аннотацией @Configuration (это к вопросу о конфигурировании через аннотации)

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Handler handler(Writer writer, Reader reader, int count) {
         return Handler(writer, reader, count);
    }
}
```

Для получения бина Вам понадобится ApplicationContext (где-то же Вы его создаете, я надеюсь :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Writer writer = new Writer();
    Reader reader = calcReader(); //вычислили нужный нам ридер по расширению файла
    Handler handler = applicationContext.getBean(Handler.class, writer, reader, count);
}
```

Правда совсем не понятно зачем Вам тут Spring, ну да ладно, дело Ваше )

Comment: Так, я немного запутался. У меня есть класс Handler, в котором вся логика. Внутри класса я делаю конструктор Handler (Writer writer, Reader reader, int count){} После этого я еще какой-то класс делаю где объявляю Handler? или под MyAppConfig понимается Producer и Consumer? 

Spring нужен для тестового задания))) не моя прихоть. Без спринг я это задание уже решил

Comment: И, дополнительный вопрос.
Как мне в контексте тогда объявлять Handler?

Раньше он был у меня захардкожен, типа

`<bean id="Handler" class="ru.testask.beans.Handler" >
<constructo-arg ref="jsonReader">
<constructor-arg ref="writer">
<constructor-arg value="10"> </bean>


<bean id="jsonReader" class="ru.testask.readers.JsonReader" ></bean>
<bean id="csvReader" class="ru.testask.readers.CsvReader" ></bean>
<bean id="xlsxReader" class="ru.testask.readers.XlsxReader" ></bean>
<bean id="writer" class="ru.testask.writer.JsonWriter" ></bean>`

А сейчас, в итоге конструтор надо убрать?

Comment: @Dred, Вы можете убрать описание бина из xml и сделать его через класс MyAppConfig. В Ваш xml можно добавить только 

     <context:component-scan base-package="ru.testask.beans"/>

 <context:annotation-config/>

Т.е. указать спрингу пакет для сканирования, и он сам обнаружит все бины. Советую к прочтению книгу Крейга Уолша "Spring в действии", читается легко.

Comment: То есть, если в кратце, вместо XML файла, я делаю целый класс, где определяю методы,  переменные в виде Bean/Resource и т.д. ? А потом это реализую в Main?

МОжно ли как-то онлайн с вами связаться? ) Почитать книгу-это конечно хорошо, но сроки горят, а может и сгорели уже)))

Comment: @Dred, пиши в телегу https://t.me/zolt85
постараюсь помочь